# Row(s) cannot be selected in MySQL Workbech editor

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench. I wrote a query to select data from a table. When I execute the select query results are displayed below the editor. However, if I want to select a row from the result set by double clicking in the first column the row does not get selected. Is there any setting to enable this service.

Comment: Check that your table has primary key or Not ? because workbench editor does not work on table having no primary key.

Comment: Table contains Primary Key

Answer (score 0):

You did not tell us which version of MySQL Workbench you are using nor which platform you are on. So I assume you have an outdated version because there was a bug (rather a regression) that prevented the row selection to work properly. This problem has already been solved in the latest release. For news and latest downloads see [our team blog](http://mysqlworkbench.org).

Comment: I am using MySQL Workbench 5.2.47 CE

Comment: So, upgrade to 6.0.6 and you should be set.